# How to make a wool hair system

Tags: particles, hair

I have been working on a sheep model for some time now but no matter what I do I cant seem to get a realistic hair system for the wool.  What are the main things i should be doing to get that look.

The look I want:

[image: Sheep1]

[image: Sheep2]

Comment: Could you post some references and what exactly you have tried and what is not working with it?

Comment: Unfortunately i no longer have my previous attempts but i tried using the kink system and it doesnt give the results i would expect.

Comment: Ok, so at least post some reference images of what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I added the references of what im looking for

Comment: Look for "blender curly hairs" in google, there are a lot of tutorials, also check  youtube. Hair Lab is add-on simplifying such things, but I'm not sure is it working with current Blender version.

Comment: https://youtu.be/JysKjqKk8kw